# How to restrict application for particular network

Tags: php, angularjs

I developed one application. That application used in multiple offices in different areas.

My requirement is, i wants to restrict  that application have to open , that offices networks only, not outside.

I am using angular as front end technology and PHP as a back end  technology.

Thanks,SrinivasaRao.CH

Comment: Ideally it should be not an application level solution, but networking. Ask your network engineer to configure firewalls correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to just host the application in the subnetwork private address range and ensure that the router does not forward any external port to your internal server. That's actually the default behaviour because port forwarding needs to be configured explicitly.

Since you're asking this as PHP question, the only possible PHP approach is to check the value of the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable on every request and verify whether it matches a white list of IP ranges. This variable is the stringified human-readable representation of the address but it can be easily converted to a normalised representation that allows direct comparisons with standard [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

- [ip2long()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) for IPv4
- [inet_pton()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) for both IPv4 and IPv6

(Beware that maths with `ip2long()` are only reliable with 64-bit versions of PHP.)

Example:

```
$network_from = inet_pton('192.168.0.1');
$network_to = inet_pton('192.168.0.255');

// Allowed visitor
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '192.168.0.5';
$visitor = inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
var_dump($visitor>=$network_from && $visitor<=$network_to); // bool(true)

// External visitor
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '151.101.1.69';
$visitor = inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
var_dump($visitor>=$network_from && $visitor<=$network_to); // bool(false)
```